# Cleanest functional way to find the largest number in javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Note that I know that there are library methods like Math.max, I just wanted to implement the function myself for learning purposes.

So I can do it with a loop via:

```
function largestNum(array) {
    if (!array.length) {
        return null;
    }
    var largest = array[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > largest) {
            largest = array[i];
        }
    }
    return largest;
}
```

Note that I needed to store the first element of the array above.

```
function largestNum(arr) {
    if (!arr.length) {
        return null;
    }
    var largest = arr.shift();
    // reduce is probably better than each here
    arr.forEach(function(value) {
        if (value > largest) {
            largest = value;
        }
    });
    return largest;
}
```

Note that I needed to get the first element via a shift (although I could use a slice). It seems to me that using shift/slice could be expensive depending on the implementation.

What is the cleanest way to write the second method using functional programming?

Comment: Check `Array.prototype.reduce()`. When the operation you're going to implement has any type of accumulation - it's `reduce`

Comment: `arr.reduce(function(a, b) { return a > b ? a : b });`

Comment: @tymeJV you stole all the fun of OP getting it themselves ;-)

Comment: Ah, I thought with reduce I would have needed to do the slice or shift anyway. Thanks, that was insightful.

Comment: What exactly do you consider "functional programming"? I don't see anything wrong with your first implementation - it's even pure, in contrast to the second snippet (which mutates `arr`).

Comment: tymJV pretty much answered this. I wanted to know how do this with a function like each/map/reduce without using splice/shift.